# How third party cookies are handled in Android browsers?

Tags: browser

Is the default browser able to write third party cookies (on Safari/iPhone, only able to read, but not to write)?
What about other Android browsers (Firefox...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer via this site: http://www.grc.com/cookies/forensics.htm

Third-party cookies are accepted by the standard browser and also by Firefox.